# Azure Data Factory Filter JSON Object Data From Notebook Activity

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am trying to call the one of the API in our databricks notebook and it will give the appropriate output. finally we will get JSON object NoteBook activity in ADF. I would like to Filter the empty array object, which is one of the array object ( nested json) needs to skip and where ever coming proper without empty value, I have filter out. please find below my sample input json from NoteBook Activity.

```
[

 {

  'day': 60.0,

  'server': 'xxxx',

  'database': 'ddddd',

  'table': 'tablename',

  'asset_id': '23232323',

  'indicate': ['value1'],

  'sub_indicator': ['sub']

  },

 {'day': 999.0,

  'server': 'sadsadsad',

  'database': 'dbbb',

  'table': 'tablename2',

  'asset_id': 'xxxxxx1',

  'indicate': ['value2'],

  'sub_indicator': ['sub2']

  },

 {'day': 30.0,

  'server': 'server3',

  'database': 'db3',

  'table': 'tablename3',

  'asset_id': 'xxxxxxx',

  'indicate': ['value3'],

  'sub_indicator': ['sub3']},

 {'day': 75.0,

  'server': 'ser',

  'database': 'db',

  'table': 'tablename',

  'asset_id': 'asdasd-adasdsa',

  'indicate': ['val1', 'val2'],

  'sub_indicator': ['sub1', 'sub2']},

 {'day': 50.0,

  'server': 'serrr',

  'database': 'dbb',

  'table': 'tablename4',

  'asset_id': 'yyyyyyyy',

  'indicate': ['value4'],

  'sub_indicator': ['sub1', 'sub2']},

 {'day': 100.0,

  'server': 'ser',

  'database': 'IRF_Everest',

  'table': 'tablename5',

  'asset_id': 'adsadasdadasdasdasd',

  'indicate': ['sub1', 'sub2'],

  'sub_indicator': ['val1']},

 {'day': 60.0,

  'server': 'server3',

  'database': 'db1',

  'table': 'tablename7',

  'asset_id': '3312312321fsdasfasf',

  'indicate': ['val1'],

  'sub_indicator': []},

 {'day': 50.0,

  'server': 'serrrrr',

  'database': 'db11',

  'table': 'tablename8',

  'asset_id': '6ac9aea1-sdsdsdsadasdsadsad',

  'indicate': ['val'],

  'sub_indicator': []},

 {'day': 60.0,

  'server': 'serrr',

  'database': 'db22',

  'table': 'tablename10',

  'asset_id': '98e3dff0-adsadsadasd',

  'indicate': ['key'],

  'sub_indicator': ['sub_key']

  }

  ]
```

below object sub_indicator filed you can see the empty value, so that we have to skip entire object while filter activity. please help us, how do we filter each object wise.

```
{'day': 60.0,

  'server': 'server3',

  'database': 'db1',

  'table': 'tablename7',

  'asset_id': '3312312321fsdasfasf',

  'indicate': ['val1'],

  **'sub_indicator': []**
},
```

After Filter, we are experiencing as below JSON like.

```
[
 {
  'day': 60.0,

  'server': 'xxxx',

  'database': 'ddddd',

  'table': 'tablename',

  'asset_id': '23232323',

  'indicate': ['value1'],

  'sub_indicator': ['sub']

  },

 {'day': 999.0,

  'server': 'sadsadsad',

  'database': 'dbbb',

  'table': 'tablename2',

  'asset_id': 'xxxxxx1',

  'indicate': ['value2'],

  'sub_indicator': ['sub2']

  },

 {'day': 30.0,

  'server': 'server3',

  'database': 'db3',

  'table': 'tablename3',

  'asset_id': 'xxxxxxx',

  'indicate': ['value3'],

  'sub_indicator': ['sub3']},

 {'day': 75.0,

  'server': 'ser',

  'database': 'db',

  'table': 'tablename',

  'asset_id': 'asdasd-adasdsa',

  'indicate': ['val1', 'val2'],

  'sub_indicator': ['sub1', 'sub2']},

 {'day': 50.0,

  'server': 'serrr',

  'database': 'dbb',

  'table': 'tablename4',

  'asset_id': 'yyyyyyyy',

  'indicate': ['value4'],

  'sub_indicator': ['sub1', 'sub2']},

 {'day': 100.0,

  'server': 'ser',

  'database': 'IRF_Everest',

  'table': 'tablename5',

  'asset_id': 'adsadasdadasdasdasd',

  'indicate': ['sub1', 'sub2'],

  'sub_indicator': ['val1']
},
{'day': 60.0,

  'server': 'serrr',

  'database': 'db22',

  'table': 'tablename10',

  'asset_id': '98e3dff0-adsadsadasd',

  'indicate': ['key'],

  'sub_indicator': ['sub_key']

  }
 ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering you already know what the array items are inside the notebook output array of object, you can directly use the filter condition as shown below:

```
items: 
@activity('Notebook1').output.runOutput

condition:
@and(not(equals(length(item().sub_indicator),0)),not(equals(length(item().indicate),0)))
```

[image]

- If these key names for array items in notebook run output are unknown, then you can add the following additional code to databricks notebook to return these key names.

```
#data is the variable I used to store the given notebook output json
keys = [k for k in data[0].keys()]
#print(keys)
req_keys  = [k for k in keys if isinstance(data[0][k],list)]
#print(req_keys)
key_obj = [{'req_keys':req_keys}]
#print(key_obj)
key_obj.extend(data)
print(key_obj)

import json
json_str = json.dumps(key_obj)
dbutils.notebook.exit(json_str)
```

[image]

- Now in data factory do the following steps.

1. Assign the notebook run output to an array variable (data).
2. Use for each activity to loop through the keys using the dynamic content `@variables('data')[0]['req_keys']` where data is the array variable.
3. Assign the current item of for each iterator to a variable (tp).
4. Use filter activity with items and condition as shown below (here item is filter iterator but not for each iterator):

```
items:
@skip(activity('Notebook1').output.runOutput,1)

condition:
@not(equals(length(item()[variables('tp')]),0))
```

5. Re-assign the value of this filter output to data variable (array).

- The following is the entire pipeline JSON for above procedure:

```
{
    "name": "pipeline1",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "Notebook1",
                "type": "DatabricksNotebook",
                "dependsOn": [],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "notebookPath": "/nb1"
                },
                "linkedServiceName": {
                    "referenceName": "AzureDatabricks1",
                    "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "loop through keys",
                "type": "ForEach",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "activity output",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "items": {
                        "value": "@variables('data')[0]['req_keys']",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    },
                    "isSequential": true,
                    "activities": [
                        {
                            "name": "Filter1",
                            "type": "Filter",
                            "dependsOn": [
                                {
                                    "activity": "for each current item",
                                    "dependencyConditions": [
                                        "Succeeded"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "items": {
                                    "value": "@skip(activity('Notebook1').output.runOutput,1)",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                },
                                "condition": {
                                    "value": "@not(equals(length(item()[variables('tp')]),0))",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "for each current item",
                            "type": "SetVariable",
                            "dependsOn": [],
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "variableName": "tp",
                                "value": {
                                    "value": "@item()",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "reassign",
                            "type": "SetVariable",
                            "dependsOn": [
                                {
                                    "activity": "Filter1",
                                    "dependencyConditions": [
                                        "Succeeded"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "variableName": "data",
                                "value": {
                                    "value": "@activity('Filter1').output.Value",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "activity output",
                "type": "SetVariable",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "Notebook1",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "variableName": "data",
                    "value": {
                        "value": "@activity('Notebook1').output.runOutput",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        "variables": {
            "data": {
                "type": "Array"
            },
            "tp": {
                "type": "String"
            }
        },
        "annotations": []
    }
}
```

- This would give you the desired output even when you don't know the names of the keys whose item value is an array and empty.

[image]